# How to allow Unfiltered HTML in a wordpress multisite install

Tags: plugin-development, filters, user-roles, capabilities

I am trying to create a custom role in a wordpress multisite environment. This role is to have the same capabilities as an admin but also have the ability to commit unfiltered HTML like super admins. I have had success in creating the role and set unfiltered_html to true, but the text editor still strips Iframes and other html elements. Below is my PHP code for the new role which I have named 'developer'.

```
function add_developer()
{
//remove role if it already exists
if( get_role('developer') ){
      remove_role( 'developer' );
}
//custom user role for unfiltered_html
$result = add_role('developer', __('Developer' ),
                  array(
                  'read' => true,
                  'activate_plugins' => true,
                  'delete_others_pages' => true,
                  'delete_others_posts' => true,
                  'delete_pages' => true,
                  'delete_posts' => true,
                  'delete_private_pages' => true,
                  'delete_private_posts' => true,
                  'delete_published_pages' => true,
                  'delete_published_posts' => true,
                  'edit_dashboard' => true,
                  'edit_others_pages'  => true,
                  'edit_others_posts' => true,
                  'edit_pages' => true,
                  'edit_posts' => true,
                  'edit_private_pages' => true,
                  'edit_private_posts' => true,
                  'edit_published_pages' => true,
                  'edit_published_posts' => true,
                  'edit_theme_options' => true,
                  'export' => true,
                  'import' => true,
                  'list_users' => true,
                  'manage_categories' => true,
                  'manage_links' => true,
                  'manage_options' => true,
                  'manage_comments' => true,
                  'promote_users' => true,
                  'publish_pages' => true,
                  'publish_posts' => true,
                  'read_private_pages' => true,
                  'read_private_posts' => true,
                  'remove_users' => true,
                  'switch_themes' => true,
                  'upload_files' => true,
                  'unfiltered_html' => true
                  )
                  );
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}

}
```

I am working in a team to convert a huge website with thousands of pages and would like to avoid giving everyone super admin access. Is there anyway that I can avoid the html filter for only specific user roles? If not is there anyway to do this for specific users? I would like to avoid altering core and don't mind removing all filtering. I am currently testing this in my functions.php file of my theme but will eventually write a plugin to this.

I am aware of the security risks that will be present due to users being able to post javascript but my team is willing to live with this if we do not have to explicitly give the whole team superadmin access.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This had me baffled for a while as well. Not exactly a solution for your problem, but this should get you on your way.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_kses_remove_filters' );
function my_kses_remove_filters() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 
    if ( my_user_has_role( 'administrator', $current_user ) )
        kses_remove_filters();
}
 
function my_user_has_role( $role = '', $user = null ) {
    $user = $user ? new WP_User( $user ) : wp_get_current_user();
 
    if ( empty( $user->roles ) )
        return;
 
    if ( in_array( $role, $user->roles ) )
        return true;
 
    return;
}
```

This action removes the filters for administrators. First it gets the role of the current user and if the role is 'administrator', it removes the filters on editing content.

This solutions draws heavily from [this page](https://www.thatstevensguy.com/wordpress/wordpress-multisite-unfiltered-html-capability/).

Comment: As per @brett's experience, the above is also no longer working for me. Currently on WP 5.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code to work for me

```
function multisite_restore_unfiltered_html( $caps, $cap, $user_id, ...$args ) {
    if ( 'unfiltered_html' === $cap && (user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) || user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ) ) {
        $caps = array( 'unfiltered_html' );
    }

    return $caps;
}

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'multisite_restore_unfiltered_html', 1, 4 );
```

https://gist.github.com/kellenmace/9e6a6fbb92ec75940f23d2a6f01c9b59

Comment: Working on version 5.9.3

Answer (score -1):

Adding an action which calls `kses_remove_filters()` didn't work for me. I actually had to hack WordPress to achieve this.

The problem is that WordPress has a global override in the method `map_meta_cap()` in `wp-includes/capabilities.php`, which ignores the `unfiltered_html` capability in a multisite install if the user is not a super admin.

Get rid of that override, and you’re sweet. Until you have to update WordPress, of course, and you’ll have to do it all over again.

```
        case 'unfiltered_html':
        // Disallow unfiltered_html for all users, even admins and super admins.
            if ( defined( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML' ) && DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML ) {
                $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
//          } elseif ( is_multisite() && ! is_super_admin( $user_id ) ) {
//              $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            } else {
            $caps[] = 'unfiltered_html';
            }
        break;
```

Comment: Modifying the WordPress Core is never a good idea.  Every time your site updates you'll have to go and do this all over again.

Comment: I know. I tried several other approaches, but this is the only thing which worked.

Comment: The Google result after this one did the trick: 
https://kellenmace.com/add-unfiltered_html-capability-to-admins-or-editors-in-wordpress-multisite/
Or steal it from this (outdated) plugin:
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/unfiltered-mu/tags/1.3.1/unfiltered-mu.php