# Javascript embedded disappears for editors

Tags: plugins, multisite, javascript, embed

WP multisite installation ver 5.2.11
Plugin Advanced Access Manager 6.5.4 licensed
 This plugin creates and manages different level of users with different privileges.
Already asked to the seller's customer service without replies

We frequently inserted an embedded code as this:

`<div id="buzzsprout-player-8580256"></div>`

`<script src="https://www.buzzsprout.com/1626286/8580256-24-05-21-l-affascinante-mondo-delle-fiabe.js?container_id=buzzsprout-player-8580256&player=small" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

We created a lower level of access for some specific editors.
For them the code embedded looses the script: after saving the page the code remains only made by the div

`<div id="buzzsprout-player-8580256"></div>`

Why does it loose the script? 
What could we do to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Multisite disallows the [`unfiltered_html`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#unfiltered_html) capability for non-super-admin (ie, any users who are not capable of performing network administration). Anyone without the `unfiltered_html` capability will *not* be able to save post content with disallowed HTML tags, including `<script>` tags.

A quick search shows that there have been attempts at modifying this behaviour, but they may have been invalidated by subsequent updates to WordPress core.

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291464/16121) for a possible solution (though it may not work anymore.)

Comment: Will the possible solution (a change in functions.php) be deleted in the next WP upgrade?

Comment: If you're referring to the `functions.php` file in your theme, it'll be left untouched in a WordPress upgrade. It *might* be updated in a theme update, however. You can ensure that it's left untouched by [creating your own plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) and putting the solution in there.